# Geographic or Physical Limitations of VLANs

Tags: ethernet, wan, vxlan

Is it incorrect to have a layer-2 broadcast domain cross long distances or multiple sites?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120931/discussion-on-question-by-ronnie-royston-geographic-or-physical-limitations-of-v).

Comment: @RonMaupin please post your answer from the comments. It would be helpful to the community.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A VLAN is a virtualized concept of a link-layer segment. That segment is connected using physical-layer links. Those links can be directly extended to up to 200 km using commonly available parts, and far beyond that using special parts, or optronic or photonic amplifiers (esp. EDFA) - effectively, the limit is your budget or the size of the planet.

However, many protocols on top of L2 expect a low latency between 'neighbor' nodes within the same segment. They may fail to work as expected on geographically distributed segments.

A link of 1000 km has a *minimum* latency of 4.8 ms due to the speed of light - with an unlikely direct, optical connection, as the crow flies, using only photonic amplification. Usually, you'll get *significantly* higher latency due to more practical pathways, and electronics and buffering along the path. Employing a carrier (for MPLS or such) can also introduce serious *fluctuations* (jitter) into the perceived link latency.

For instance, relying on xSTP for a redundant, loop-free topology may fail when the tree doesn't properly reconverge because of fluctuations in latency exceeding the design limits. Also, long links are expensive and redundant links blocked by STP don't earn any money.

L2 is often managed using broadcasting (e.g. ARP) which is highly inefficient on a large geographic scale. ARP might even fail or address conflicts may be masked because of high latency (when a near and a remote node share the same IP).

Also, with a partial failure/shutdown of one location (or possibly just a switch reboot) or its coming back online, *all* your L2 network is impacted.

In contrast, *routed* links can be utilized with much better efficiency. Using a proper routing protocol you can build a redundant mesh without the limitations of STP. ECMP and PBR enable better utilization of and better traffic control over your links.

And last but not least, any link-layer problem stays limited to the local segment and doesn't influence your entire network.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston A VLAN is a link-layer segment, the most common use for "segment".

Comment: Here's a Cisco documented [deployment senario](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9300/software/release/17-4/configuration_guide/lyr2/b_174_lyr2_9300_cg/configuring_vlan_mapping.html#concept_zx3_hnz_ghb) i just found for it, BTW

Comment: That guide talks in no way about geographically separated sites. Of course, a VLAN configuration guide tells you how you can configure VLANs. It doesn't tell you how to design your network though.

Comment: it says `In a typical deployment of VLAN mapping, you want service provider to provide a transparent switching infrastructure that includes customers’ switches at the remote location as a part of local site. This allows customers to use the same VLAN ID space and run Layer 2 control protocols seamlessly across the provider network.`

Comment: Yes, it's talking about VLAN connectivity, not about good design. It's certainly possible but most likely not recommendable.

Comment: Zac, i hear you, it seems to violate what they used to teach/preach. However, it might be worth considering that it is not actually bad design practice on it's face and that in fact such a design could actually be operationally superior (least expensive/most features/most simple/no downtime).

Comment: Decent switches are L3 anyway, so routing doesn't cost anything. We're just providing advice, it's your network.

Comment: Not free. Routing breaks layer2 adjacency which is sometimes desired (think wanting a DMZ port at a location). Subtle but important and consequential losses.

Comment: You can easily create a DMZ at each location where it's needed. Of course, it's a bit more complicated, but as I was trying to point out a routed network scales much better. Do as you like but you won't find many supporters for "one giant L2 network" here.

Comment: noone is advocating 'one giant L2 network'  and when you say that are you speaking of giant in terms of physical port count per broadcast domain, or CAM/MAC table limitations, or CPU limitations, or host per broadcast domain, or geographic distance, or what?

Comment: Port count, host/node count and geographic distance.

Comment: So, since we see it deployed and we see Cisco offering SP features to support it, maybe we should view it as a band-aid/patch solution, not unlike IP GRE Tunnels.

Comment: your second sentence is inaccurate. a virtual LAN can exist across underlying layer 3 network, e.g. VXLAN.

Comment: also the 6th paragraph is inaccurate. e.g. a closet switch can die without impacting the rest of the LAN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120965/discussion-between-zac67-and-ronnie-royston).

Comment: respectfully, i don't want to chat. i delete comments as revisions are made. just trying to produce a better quality answer for the community. i think your answer is not bad. i'll delete the comments now that you've seen them. just thought you might want to fix the technically wrong parts.